# Can I connect Ground from UPS outlet to another outlet which has no Ground?

Tags: electrical, grounding, safety

Simplified situation: I live in a rented room. My room has two two outlets, namely Outlet A and Outlet B.

Outlet A has connections only from main supply. It has no connection to UPS. And, it has two wires in them, one for Live and another for Neutral. Ground port is vacant with no connections in it.

Outlet B has connection from UPS(sine-wave). This outlet comes with Live, Neutral and Ground wire (confirmed with Multimeter). I am not supposed to use this outlet.

---

I get tingling sensation while using my laptop when laptop is being charged. Also, if I use earphone with blanket on me, I get static shocks inside my ear. So, I want Ground connection for my electrical appliances and I can't use outlet B. Load on outlet A is of roughly 215Watts.

Thus, can I just plug a wire in Ground port of Outlet B and connect that wire to Ground Port of outlet A?( I assume, all connections to ground are basically via the same wire.) Will this be safe?

Location: Asia, India

Readings of Outlet B:
Live and Neutral: 218V

Neutral and Ground: 60V

Live and Ground: 170V

Comment: Is Outlet B the outlet the UPS plugs into, or...?

Comment: UPS power is delivered via outlet B. Whenever mains is off, outlet B has still got electricity in it. In both outlets, Outlet A and B, I can plug in load. It is just that outlet B is backed up with sine wave UPS.

Comment: it would be safer. best would be to bring the outlet up to spec though.

Comment: I didn't get you @dandavis. Could you please elaborate "to bring the outlet up to spec"?

Comment: I don't know about india, but outlet grounding most places has been required for a long time, and for good reason. You might be able to force your landlord to fix it. Establishing a common ground among your equipment should get rid of some of the symptoms you describe.